# ProGuard obfuscation issue

Tags: proguard, obfuscation

Hello I was obfuscating my .jars with ProGuard but I keep getting this message:

> Reading library jar [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\rt.jar]
>
> (The system cannot find the path specified)

It is the right path for the rt.jar. Is there a solution to fix this?

Comment: same problem here? any news on how to solve this?